# Catching bulk events in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have `Book` model. It has some fields like `title`, `year publish` and etc. Also, i have overrided `save()` method. When new books is adding, it checks if book exsists, it creating new directory with name `self.title` in `MEDIA_ROOT` path.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        book_dir = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, self.title)

        # check that at least one file is loading
        if all([self.pdf, self.fb2, self.epub]):
            raise ValidationError("At least 1 file should be uploaded!")
        # create book's directory if it not exists
        if os.path.exists(book_dir):
            raise ValidationError("This book is already exists!")
        else:
            os.mkdir(book_dir)

        # rename and edit storage location of books to book_dir
        for field in [self.image, self.pdf, self.fb2, self.epub]:
            field.storage.location = book_dir

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Also i have overrided `delete()` method, that just remove directory of deleted book.

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    book_dir = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, self.title)

    rmtree(book_dir)
    super().delete(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" delete() method.
```

`delete()` method works well if i delete only 1 book.
But, if i want to delete multiple files (all actions take place in the admin panel), only DB records got deleted.

So, i want to just catch this moment to remove directory of deleted book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `pre_delete` signal could be useful here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#pre-delete